# How to uncheck checkbox values in custom meta-box each time a new post is created?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin and I have a custom meta-box which contains some checkboxes. Now I wanted to save state of these checkboxes even after page refresh, hence I'm doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='my_meta_box_check[]']");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.hasAttribute("value")) {
            setupBox(box);
        }
    }

    function setupBox(box) {
        var storageId = box.getAttribute("value");
        var oldVal    = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
        box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;

        box.addEventListener("change", function() {
            localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked);
        }); 
    }
})();
</script>
```

And it works. But what happens is, whenever a new post is created, the checkboxes are checked with old values from last post. How do I refresh or uncheck all checkboxes when the post is created for the first time?
I also tried deleting post meta from database if the post status is not yet published, like this:

```
if(get_post_status($post->ID)==='publish'){
    echo "<b>"."Post is published!"."</b></br>";
}
else
{
    global $wpdb;   
    global $post;
    echo "<b>"."Post is not published!"."</b></br>";    
    $wpdb->query("DELETE from wp_postmeta where post_id LIKE '$post->ID' AND meta_key='my_meta_box_check'");  

}
```

It executes the query, but the checkboxes are checked with values from the previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to clear your local storage after you submit the post.

If you want to remove/clean all the values from local storage than use

```
localStorage.clear();
```

And if you want to remove the specific item from local storage than use the following code

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```